# использование памяти ProcessPoolExecutor в Python

Tags: python, память, asyncio, multiprocessing

я использую **ProcessPoolExecutor** вместе с **loop.run_in_executor()** из asyncio. память после выполнения корутины не очищается, процесс все также держит ее в себе. прочитав https://bugs.python.org/issue41699 и https://bugs.python.org/issue37909 я пришел к выводу, что подобные пулы всегда надо явно закрывать методом shutdown (или использовать контекстный менеджер), а затем заново открывать.

правильно ли это? таким образом, в моем асинхронном приложении мне надо будет периодически закрывать и заново открывать пул, чтобы очищать память (открывать его контекстным менеджером каждый раз при вызове  в моем случае неэффективно).

Comment: Смысл пула в том, что они позволяют сэкономить время за счет памяти. Если пул закрывать после каждого использования, то смысла в нем нет никакого. В первую очередь, ответьте зачем вы используете пул?

Comment: @RomanKonoval асинхронный бот, в нем можно цитаты создавать. они кушают много цпу, вот я и отправляю подобные задачи в пул

Comment: @RomanKonoval и еще, я отметил, что пересоздавать пул буду не перед каждым использованием, конечно же. это будет периодически в фоне происходить

Comment: А смотрел что там в памяти лежит?  течет ли она? нет смысла пересоздавать пул если на следующей операции выделится ещё раз столько же.